# Autosys JIL for removing start time of job

Tags: scheduler, autosys

I have a job in autosys and I need to update it to remove the starting time completely.
Currently the start time is set to run at 10pm every night.

```
update_job: myjobname
start_times:
```

Do I leave the `start_times` blank as above or do I change it to `start_times: " "` 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to keep it as blank. However, along with this you have to remove the **days_of_week** or **run_calendar** as applicable:

```
update_job: myjobname
start_times:
days_of_week:
```

If you are looking to remove this from schedule, another way is to just update the boolean value of **date_condition**

```
update_job: myjobname
date_conditions: n
```

here "n" would mean not to follow the timings. It can be mentioned as 0 or 1. The user has to force start the job on need basis.